# Docker MariaDB volume not found in container?

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, mariadb, virtualization

This `docker-compose.yml` file works fine:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: docker-test
    container_name: docker-test
    ports:
      - 9000:80
    volumes:
      - '/var/www/docker-test/:/srv/app/'      
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    container_name: docker-test-db
    ports:
      - 33061:3306
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - '/docker-db-data/docker-test/:/var/lib/mysql/'
```

The volume in the host is created fine (`/docker-db-data/docker-test/`) but when I "SSH" to the container, I can't seem to find `/var/lib/mysql` E.g.,

```
[root@localhost docker]# docker exec -it docker-test bash
root@2d03e775f531:# ls /var/lib/mysql
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/mysql': No such file or directory
```

Is this expected? If not, where is it actually located?

Comment: You don't mount that volume into the `app` container, so you shouldn't expect to see it if you `docker exec` into it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I see, my impression was `/docker-db-data/docker-test/` from host will sync in real-time with `/var/lib/mysql/` from the container.

Comment: In the specific container you mount it into.  If you `docker exec docker-test-db ls /var/lib/mysql` you should see it.

Comment: @DavidMaze Well you're right! I missed that `-db` prefix. You can put that as answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `volumes:` attach to specific containers.  Your `docker exec docker-test` command attaches to the `app:` container, but you actually want to attach to the `db:` container, which you've named `docker-test-db`.  If you add that `-db` on the end, it will work:

```
docker exec docker-test-db ls /var/lib/mysql
```